# Selenium clickat with AJAX and randomly generated target ids

Tags: html, ajax, selenium

I am using selenium to automate some IT admin tasks, a NAS (that I access through an internal webpage) needs some external drives swapped out. I think the web interface uses AJAX to dynamically change the screen around and that generally messes with my ability to navigate around the webpage using selenium.

The NAS supplier has a live demo of the web interface at:
http://www.synology.com/us/products/demo/index.php

This is pretty much identical to the web interface for the NAS.

Anyone have any hints on how to navigate around this type of page? (How do I find the element locator to clickat() to get the control panel open for example). The ids seem to randomly generate every time I log in, to something like "target id=ext-gen525"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the elements by using a CSS or XPATH locators.
And give some wait time between selenium commands(by using proper wait conditions) as your app uses AJAX controls.

Here is the sample code to click on 'Control panel' and then click on 'User' (in demo web interface: http://www.synology.com/us/products/demo/index.php)

```
    //After login to http://demo.synology.com:5000
    selenium.click("//div[text()='Control Panel']");
    Thread.sleep(3000); // Use proper wait conditions
    selenium.click("//div[text()='User']");
```

Comment: Yep, this works and I am following what you are saying. I can use the firefox addons DOM Inspector and XPather to then 'select element by click' to get something sensible to target, such as the text on the button.  




The selenium IDE I am using has pause instead of sleep but I have stepped through the script and it works, I will post it once I have finished it off in case someone has the exact problem as me and just wants to cut and paste the answer.

Comment: selenium.open("/webman/index.cgi");  
selenium.type("id=login_username", "admin");    
selenium.type("id=login_passwd", "synology");  
selenium.click("id=login_submit");  
Thread.sleep(3000);  
selenium.click("//div[text()='Control Panel']");  
Thread.sleep(3000);  
selenium.click("//div[text()='External']");  
Thread.sleep(3000);  
selenium.click("//div[text()='SATALink SPIF225A']");  
Thread.sleep(3000);  
selenium.click("//button[text()='Eject']");  
Thread.sleep(3000);  
selenium.click("//button[text()='Yes']");  
Thread.sleep(3000);  
selenium.click("//button[text()='Logout']");